# Sort users in sharepoint group

Tags: workflow, groups, sorting

I have several groups of users that have either Create or Approve permissions, each group with Create permissions has a matching Approve group, so that anytime User1 in CreateGroup1 creates an item this item has to be approved by all the users in ApproveGroup1.

I am running a workflow every time an item is created on a list and I am able to choose the correct approval group.

My problem is that I need the approval to be done serially (one user at a time) and Sharepoint Groups sorts users alphabetically making me unable to pick the order in which users are attributed a task.

Any way to sort the users or another way to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the users up in a list instead of just using the out of the box security groups, you have more control. You could create a column that will state their place in the sequence (1, 2, 3)Then you could modify your approval workflow using SharePoint Designer and have it step through in the order in which you specify using lookups to that list.

Comment: Ok, so if I do this and have a lookup column to this list of users I can check which list was selected in my workflow and assign the tasks to each user on the list but this leads to several IF statements. Is there a way, to automate the assignment of tasks? Something that would loop through the total number of records on the approvers list?

Comment: With SharePoint Designer, there isn't a way yet to do true loops.